# problema con postgresql para insertar

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy teniendo problemas, tengo este query:
select substring (bloque15min, 1,10)::date, substring (bloque15min, 18,22)::time, count (*), count (case when tiempo_respuesta<20 then tiempo_respuesta END),count (case when fue_atendida='Si' then fue_atendida END) from tabla_1
group by 1,2 order by 1,2,

Estoy usando un select para extraer los datos de la tabla 1 y llenar solo lo que ocupo para la tabla 2, el problema es que en mi tabla 1 nada mas trae los bloques de hora desde las 07:15 am y hasta la ultima hora que se tiene registro de una llamada, lo que necesito es que para mi tabla 2 si se ponga la hora desde las 00:00 am hasta las 23:45 PM, y que si no tiene llamada un bloque de hora que no se omita, si no que tambien se muestre en 0. Estoy usando postgresql.

Comment: Sería muy útil que editaras la pregunta para incluir la información que pusiste como una respuesta. También podrías incluir una muestra de la tabla de la que se va a extraer la información y tal vez un ejemplo de cómo quieres que sea el resultado que esperas obtener.

Answer (score 0):

En la primera imagen muestro el resultado del query pero necesito que en la segunda columna empice desde las 00:00 am, 00:15 am y asi sucesivamente y que si no hay llamadas en algun bloque de hora aparezcan y no se omitan como en este caso aparece en mi query.

Comment: Hola. Tal vez quieras editar tu pregunta y poner ahí tu explicación en vez de hacer una respuesta que seguramente no va a ser la solución